# How to reduce a DataFrame to two DataFrames then sum rows of each data frame into new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, groupingby

I have a dataframe:

| sensor_id | timestamp | current | apparent_power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.944369920 | 1.550 | 101.5 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.959425024 | 0.284 | 20.4 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:01.945563136 | 1.549 | 101.6 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:01.950393856 | 0.286 | 20.2 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:02.944880896 | 1.547 | 100.6 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:02.949997056 | 0.290 | 21.6 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:03.944605184 | 1.547 | 100.9 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:03.949342976 | 0.290 | 21.8 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:04.944967936 | 1.548 | 100.9 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:04.950715136 | 0.285 | 20.5 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:05.944571904 | 1.547 | 100.7 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:05.952841984 | 0.284 | 20.2 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:06.945287936 | 1.548 | 100.8 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:06.950289920 | 0.287 | 20.8 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:07.944841984 | 1.547 | 100.7 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:07.962969088 | 0.290 | 21.8 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:08.945434112 | 1.550 | 103.1 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:08.950361088 | 0.281 | 20.1 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:09.944396032 | 1.551 | 103.8 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:09.949807872 | 0.285 | 21.1 |

My end aim to so push sensor 1 into sensor 2 line, summing the row of each only to create the two row total:

| timestamp_0 | timestamp_1 | total_current | total_apparent_power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:00.944369920 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.959425024 | 1.834 | 121.9 |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:01.945563136 | 2024-02-01 00:00:01.950393856 | 1.835 | 121.6 |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:02.944880896 | 2024-02-01 00:00:02.949997056 | xxx | xxx |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:03.944605184 | 2024-02-01 00:00:03.949342976 | xxx | xxx |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:04.944967936 | 2024-02-01 00:00:04.950715136 | xxx | xxx |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:05.944571904 | 2024-02-01 00:00:05.952841984 | xxx | xxx |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:06.945287936 | 2024-02-01 00:00:06.950289920 | xxx | xxx |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:07.944841984 | 2024-02-01 00:00:07.962969088 | xxx | xxx |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:08.945434112 | 2024-02-01 00:00:08.950361088 | xxx | xxx |
| 2024-02-01 00:00:09.944396032 | 2024-02-01 00:00:09.949807872 | xxx | xxx |

I have took the timestamps and grouped them by second and hour to produce:

| sensor_id | timestamp | current | apparent_power | seconds | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.944369920 | 1.550 | 101.5 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.959425024 | 0.284 | 20.4 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:01.945563136 | 1.549 | 101.6 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:01.950393856 | 0.286 | 20.2 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:02.944880896 | 1.547 | 100.6 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:02.949997056 | 0.290 | 21.6 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:03.944605184 | 1.547 | 100.9 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:03.949342976 | 0.290 | 21.8 | 3 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:04.944967936 | 1.548 | 100.9 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:04.950715136 | 0.285 | 20.5 | 4 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:05.944571904 | 1.547 | 100.7 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:05.952841984 | 0.284 | 20.2 | 5 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:06.945287936 | 1.548 | 100.8 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:06.950289920 | 0.287 | 20.8 | 6 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:07.944841984 | 1.547 | 100.7 | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:07.962969088 | 0.290 | 21.8 | 7 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:08.945434112 | 1.550 | 103.1 | 8 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:08.950361088 | 0.281 | 20.1 | 8 | 0 |
| 0 | 2024-02-01 00:00:09.944396032 | 1.551 | 103.8 | 9 | 0 |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 00:00:09.949807872 | 0.285 | 21.1 | 9 | 0 |

I have something that starts to do it, but falls over if the data has a missing sensor reading:

```
second_tracker = 0
a_row = 0
b_row = 0

for i, row in test_file_df.iterrows():
   
   if row['seconds'] != second_tracker:
       second_tracker += 1
       # store totals
       a_cur = a_row['current']
       b_cur = b_row['current']
       total_current = a_cur + b_cur
       
       a_app_power = a_row['apparent_power']
       b_app_power = b_row['apparent_power']
       total_app_power = a_app_power + b_app_power
       
       new_row = {'timestamp_0': a_row['timestamp'],'timestamp_1': b_row['timestamp'], 'total_current': total_current, 'total_app_power': total_app_power}
       print(new_row)
       power_sum_df.loc[len(power_sum_df)] = new_row
       a_row = 0
       b_row = 0
   
   if row['sensor_id'] == 0:
       a_row = row
   else:
       b_row = row
```

It stops when there is no matching sensor row create due to sensor missing - i.e. row is sensor 0, next row is also sensor 0 as previous sensor 1 was lost.

I have tried splitting into to two DF and tries to sum row 1 + row 1 but could understand how to add the two rows into a new data frame and sum only two columns while copying up the next row timestamp.

Can anyone help - even a better way of pulling out the alternate rows into one row.
I tried to use unstack, group and agg to no avail.

Update***** data shows irregular records within the single time second:

| line no | sensor_id | timestamp | current | apparent_power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 2024-01-25 00:00:02.977937920 | 1.502 | 370.9 |
| 5 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:02.983158016 | 0.293 | 72.4 |
| 6 | 0 | 2024-01-25 00:00:03.977388032 | 1.503 | 371.1 |
| 7 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:03.995464960 | 0.284 | 70.3 |
| 8 | 0 | 2024-01-25 00:00:04.978688000 | 1.500 | 370.6 |
| 9 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:05.025767168 | 0.287 | 70.9 |
| 10 | 0 | 2024-01-25 00:00:05.980681984 | 1.495 | 369.0 |
| 11 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:06.031785984 | 0.286 | 70.7 |
| 12 | 0 | 2024-01-25 00:00:06.977396992 | 1.497 | 369.7 |
| 13 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:06.984870912 | 0.280 | 69.3 |
| 14 | 0 | 2024-01-25 00:00:07.979064832 | 1.495 | 369.1 |
| 15 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:07.983921920 | 0.282 | 69.6 |

Desired Result: There is logic applied where there are more than 2 records in a single second - always taking one of sensor0 and one of sensor 1.
If there is only a single sensor reading within the second, then use the previous second corresponding sensor value for the sum.

| lines joined | sensor_0 | sensor_1 | timestamp_0 | timestamp_1 | total_current | total_apparent_power | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 & 5 | 0 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:02.977937920 | 2024-01-25 00:00:02.983158016 | 1.795 | 443.2 | Normal |
| 6 & 7 | 0 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:03.977388032 | 2024-01-25 00:00:03.995464960 | 1.787 | 441.4 | Normal |
| 8 & 7 | 0 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:04.978688000 | use line 7 sensor 1 as no sensor 1 in this second | 1.784 | 440.9 | use previous sensor 1 |
| 10 & 9 | 0 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:05.980681984 | 2024-01-25 00:00:05.025767168 | 1.782 | 439.9 | swap so ts_0 is sensor_0 |
| 12 & 13 | 0 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:06.977396992 | 2024-01-25 00:00:06.984870912 | 1.777 | 439.0 | use last sens0, and last sens1 of second |
| 14 & 15 | 0 | 1 | 2024-01-25 00:00:07.979064832 | 2024-01-25 00:00:07.983921920 | 1.777 | 438.7 | Normal |

I have also modified the group for hour, min & second to put it in the grouping I am after.

```
power_agg_df = (test_file_df.groupby([ts.dt.hour, ts.dt.minute, ts.dt.second], sort=False)
               .agg(** {
                   "sensor_0" : ("sensor_id", "first"),
                   "sensor_1" : ("sensor_id", "last"),
                   "timestamp_0" : ("timestamp", "first"),
                   "timestamp_1" : ("timestamp", "last"),
                   "total_current" : ("current", "sum"),
                   "total_apparent_power" : ("apparent_power", "sum"),
                   
               }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a loop, you can use the ([`hour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)/[`second`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.second.html)) as a grouper to [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) the operations you need :

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
grp = {"hour": ts.dt.hour, "second": ts.dt.second} # +more ?
# grp = {"time": ts.dt.floor("s").dt.time} # 3-components of time

#1 reduce the groups with more than two identical censors
uniq = (df.assign(**grp).sort_values([*grp, "sensor_id"]).loc[
        lambda x: ~x.duplicated(subset=[*grp, "sensor_id"], keep="last")])

#2 look for the previous cursors to complete the groups having a single one
miss = df.groupby(list(grp.values()))["sensor_id"].transform("nunique").eq(1)
exte = (uniq.mask(miss | uniq["sensor_id"].eq(uniq["sensor_id"].shift(-1)))
           .ffill().loc[miss].convert_dtypes())#.assign(timestamp=None))

#3 swap the censors in the groups with a leading censor-1
cln = (pd.concat([uniq, exte if not exte.empty else None])
         .sort_values(["sensor_id", *grp]))
out = (
        cln.astype({"line no": "str"})
        .groupby(list(grp.values()))
            .agg(**{
                # feel free to comment (#) any agg
            "lines_joined": ("line no", " & ".join),
            "sensor_0": ("sensor_id", "first"),
            "sensor_1": ("sensor_id", "last"),
            "timestamp_0": ("timestamp", "first"),
            "timestamp_1": ("timestamp", "last"),
            "total_current": ("current", "sum"),
            "total_apparent_power": ("apparent_power", "sum")
        })
     .reset_index(names=[*grp]) # to show up the groups
    #.reset_index(drop=True) # or just drop them if optional
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Timeless, this solves the problem of getting the data processed - using ‘first’ and ‘last’.
However I the problem is when there is more than 2 readings within one second, or if there is only one.
This solution picks the first and last, but that means there are duplicates created or  (e.g.) 3 records in one second: sensor 1, sensor 0, sensor 1 - then both will be sensor 1 and incorrect accumulation.
I am reading up now about this way you proposed - is there a way to put logic into where ‘last’ is - such as if sensor id and ts matches, then take the previous record vaue?

Comment: @Steve, can you update your example (I/O) to include those scenarios, please ?

Comment: Hi Timeless, I added some update to the bottom of my post - I hope that's the correct way to add to posts.

Comment: Thanks but that alters your original post significantly. Nonetheless, I updated my answer to (*hopefully*) address the three different scenarios (other than the normal one). NB: For the groups like second `4`, if you actually need `None` instead of the value of the previous timestamp, uncomment `#.assign(timestamp=None))` in `exte` and use `lambda s: s.head(1)` and `lambda s: s.tail(1)` as aggregations for the timestamps instead of `first` and `last`, respectively. Also, make sure the original `df` is sorted. If not, add `df.sort_values("timestamp", inplace=True)` at the very top of the code.

Comment: Timeless - amazing. It's much more complicated than I imagined. After a little modification it works, and have checked its output - really appreciated.
I need to study the area #1 and #2 and pull it apart to understand its steps - I am sure this method of cleaning intermittent data will be very useful.
Apologies the whole problem wasn't communicated from the start clearly.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed solution**

```py
grouped = (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2)
             .agg({'timestamp': 'first', 'current': 'sum', 'apparent_power': 'sum'}))

grouped['timestamp2'] = grouped.groupby(level=0)['timestamp'].transform('last')

grouped = (grouped[['timestamp', 'timestamp2', 'current', 'apparent_power']]
             .rename(columns={'current': 'total_current', 'apparent_power': 'total_apparent_power'})
             )
```

**Display**

```
>>> grouped.columns
Index(['timestamp', 'timestamp2', 'total_current', 'total_apparent_power'], dtype='object')
```

```py
>>> grouped
                      timestamp  ... total_apparent_power
0 2024-02-01 00:00:00.944369920  ...                121.9
1 2024-02-01 00:00:01.945563136  ...                121.8
2 2024-02-01 00:00:02.944880896  ...                122.2
3 2024-02-01 00:00:03.944605184  ...                122.7
4 2024-02-01 00:00:04.944967936  ...                121.4
5 2024-02-01 00:00:05.944571904  ...                120.9
6 2024-02-01 00:00:06.945287936  ...                121.6
7 2024-02-01 00:00:07.944841984  ...                122.5
8 2024-02-01 00:00:08.945434112  ...                123.2
9 2024-02-01 00:00:09.944396032  ...                124.9
```

Inspired from @Timeless proposition, another way of reducing this code in one line using `//` trick :

```py
grouped = (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2)
             .agg(**{
            "timestamp_0": ("timestamp", "first"),
            "timestamp_1": ("timestamp", "last"),
            "total_current": ("current", "sum"),
            "total_apparent_power": ("apparent_power", "sum")
        })
             )
```